# Is there any way to sum all sub array item and then multiply all sub arrays using a 'for' or 'for-of' loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i want to create a function using for() or for of() loop, which take an nested array as argument then add and multiply its item.
Suppose, myArray = [[5,6],[9,2],[4,8]] 
Now i want to process it like: [[5+6] * [9+2] * [4+8]] 
**I solve it using .map() and .reduce(), but is there any way to do same using classic for() or for of() loop**. this is my trial.

```
let myArray = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

function multyPlus(array) {
    resul = 0
    for (const subArray of array) {
        for (const num of subArray) {
            resul += num
        }
        resul *= subArray
    }
return resul
}

console.log(multyPlus(myArray));
//Nan
```

Comment: Don't use `map` as an iterator construct. If you're not using the array `map` returns, you're using the wrong function. (And basically don't use `reduce` for anything if you're not an experienced FP programmer.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code in the question doesn't try to use `for` or `for-of`. Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Of course, `map` and `reduce` are basically loops abstracted away, so you can do it by replacing the calls with the appropriate loops.

Comment: Please update your question with your best attempt at resolving this yourself.  Let's see your loop!  And then explain what's not working with your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Like This:

```js
let myArray = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

function multyPlus(_array){
 var out = 1;
 for(var key1 in _array){
  var out2 = 0;
  for(var key2 in _array[key1]){
   out2 += _array[key1][key2];
  }
  out = out * out2;
 }
 return out;
}
console.log(multyPlus(myArray));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now i got it.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a two step system that first adds the numbers, then multiplies it to the previous numbers:

```
function sum(array) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var item of array)
        total += item;
    return total;
}

var myArray = [[5,6],[9,2],[4,8]];

var output = 1;
for (var item of myArray)
    output *= sum(item);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not sure what variable I didn't define. Can you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I fixed it. Thanks, I didn't know I had to declare the variables inside the loop!

Comment: My pleasure! FWIW, since you're using ES2015+ anyway (`for-of` was added in ES2015), I'd recommend using `const` for those so they're scoped to the loop (`let` if you wanted to be able to change them in the loop, but you don't change them in the above, so...). `for (const item of myArray)` If you're curious about `let`, `const`, `for-of`, and how these new things work, I cover them in my new book coming out in a couple of months, details on my profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate `adder` and `multiplier` functions -

```js
const adder = (nums = []) =>
{ let r = 0
  for (const n of nums)
    r += n
  return r
}

const multiplier = (nums = []) =>
{ let r = 1
  for (const n of nums)
    r *= n
  return r
}

const myCalc = (input = []) =>
{ const r = []

  for (const x of input)
    r.push(adder(x))

  return multiplier(r)
}

const result =
  myCalc([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
  
console.log(result) // 231
```

That said, I think the functional approach is superior when you use named functions. Each function is highly reusable and there's virtually no room for bugs to hide -

```js
const add = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x + y

const mult = (x = 0, y = 0) =>
  x * y

const sum = (nums = []) =>
  nums.reduce(add, 0)

const product = (nums = []) =>
  nums.reduce(mult, 1)

const myCalc = (input = []) =>
  product(input.map(sum)) // <-- easy peasy!
  
const result =
  myCalc([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
  
console.log(result) // 231
```

If you have something against `map` and `reduce`, you can write `myCalc` and `sum` by hand using simple recursion -

```js
const sum = ([ x, ...more ]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? 0
    : x + sum(more)

const myCalc = ([ x, ...more ]) =>
  x === undefined
    ? 1
    : sum(x) * myCalc(more)
  
const result =
  myCalc([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
  
console.log(result) // 231
```

Comment: Many thanks. As i am very new to programming, and starting to learn javascript only 25 days, your answer is advance for me. I understand and familiar with  mscdeveloper's answe. But i understand your solution is more elegant and reusable. Hope i can understand your solution in near future. Thank you again.

Comment: smrakib, one of the reason I love StackOverflow is you can see a problem solved using many variety of techniques. Each technique has its unique qualities. I wish you all the best on your journey :D